# What is the conversion of fresh basil to Frozen blanched basil

Tags: measurements, frozen, basil, blanching

I grew a lot of fresh basil.  I blanched and then froze it to make pesto at a later date ,but I did not measure it beforehand . So I was wondering what One 1 cup of fresh basil is equivalent to how much Frozen blanched basil? I blanched and froze my fresh basil but did not measure it beforehand.

Comment: I'm trying to picture a cup of fresh basil, and the quantity would surely be so variable that just eyeballing it would be equally accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking blanching causes leaves to drop a lot.  I suggest you cast your mind back and think about how much smaller it looked after blanching than before. This is easy for me as I tend to use the same type of container for picking fresh produce and for freezing.  You don't need great precision here; after all basil is fairly variable in the strength of its flavour.

Alternatively, simply use a recipe that works by weight.  Blanching shouldn't change the weight appreciably if you get the basil reasonably dry afterwards, so 1g of fresh basil is the same as 1g of blanched, to within the precision you need.